# Could high-latency clients affect the processing time of other requests on a server?

Tags: performance, http, networking, server, latency

Basically, I have a setup with one single Go-Lang HTTP server and multiple clients (about 100). All the clients are in the same data-center and the RTT between those clients and the server is less than 1ms. However, for some of them, I emulated the latency with `tc netem` and set the RTT to 50ms or 250ms.

For all the setups, I calculated how much time it takes to service a client request (calculations done from client) and classified them into histogram buckets. I noticed that when there are high-latency clients (50ms or 250ms) in the setup, the time needed to process requests coming from the other clients (i.e without latency: ~< 1ms) becomes larger which could mean that high-latency clients are affecting the processing time of other clients (without latency). To what degree, this observation can be true ? Is the server somehow affected by high-latency clients and hence takes longer to process requests of other clients ?

Comment: Sure, slow clients _could_ influence others. But that is highly dependent on both the code and the network, so I doubt this question could be meaningfully answered at this point.

Comment: @bnaecker the code is so big and diverse that I cannot post anything. But the idea is that the server serves HTTP endpoints using Go's default HTTP server and endpoints multiplexer. The clients GET objects from the server, sometimes modify them and then POST them again ( concurrency is managed optimistically with object versioning). Can you elaborate more and possibly provide a concrete example of your statement ?

Comment: I mean, for example, that the application protocol will greatly affect how clients influence each other. Imagine that the server was required to wait for those modified POST requests, maybe because it needs to somehow communicate those changes to other clients. That would effectively serialize requests, so the latency of individual clients is crucial. But again, this is an example, and without details of your code, it's not really possible to answer this question. You could read the Go HTTP code for hints. Or just benchmark.